# return index array with wildcards

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that essentially "searches" an index and returns the array of matches. However when I introduce wildcards it no longer works. What I am trying to accomplsh is the ability to search part of a string and return all values that has that string within it.

Example:

- Cells A1:C10 contain item name, item location, and description respectively.
- Cell D1 has the word "wrench" in it.
- Cell D2:D10 has a formula that will return ALL matches with the descriptive word wrench in it (box wrench, wrench, torque wrench, etc...).

The following formula is what I am using and it works ONLY if I have the exact wording as described. in this case it will ONLY return wrench matches and not the other types of wrenches.

```
INDEX(Table2[Item Location],SMALL(IF(("*"&$D$1&"*"="*"&Table2[Item Description]&"*"),MATCH(ROW(Table2[Item Description]), ROW(Table2[Item Description]),0), ""), ROWS($A$1:A1))))
```

I am looking to get Item Locations returned for ALL wrench types and not just "wrench".

Comment: What makes you think that wildcards that work in the file system are the same in Excel? A `*` is just a `*` in Excel.

Comment: You have to do something like `=NOT(ISERR(SEARCH("wrench","box wrench")))` to get a `TRUE` or a `FALSE` value if you can find the substring or not.

Comment: If one has O365 you could try: `=FILTER(Table2[Item Location],ISNUMBER(FIND("*"&D1&"*",Table2[Description])))`. Beware that doing so you match anything where wrench is a substring, even awrenchb.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using O365, that was my first thought too. Also you can definitely use wildcards in Index Match, for example:

=INDEX(Table2[Item location],MATCH("*"&$D$1&"*",Table2[Item Description],0))

Will return the first item that includes the string you are searching. Unfortunately I can't seem to get it to cooperate with my above formula.

Comment: If no O365, try the following array entered formula: `=INDEX(Table2[Item Location],SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("*"&D$1&"*",Table2[Description])),ROW(Table2[Description]),""),ROW(A1)))`. Drag down.

Comment: I am getting caught up in the "Value if true" Where you have ROW(Table2[Description])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found was that you cannot seem to use SMALL when working with wildcards, otherwise Index Match allows you to use wildcards. My solution after much trial and error was to use the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[Item Location],AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(Table2[Item Description])-ROW($A$2)+1)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$1,Table2[Item Description])),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")
```

This will return any matching item description regardless of characters (Partials work) and index the Item Location.